# Simplifying transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to simplify this matrix. It is the basic transformation matrix I came up with that is needed to generate [base-motif fractals](http://www.2dcurves.com/fractal/fractal.html#basemotiffractal).

**Edit:**

Suppose we have a base pattern(**blue**) and a motif(**red**), explained in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLH7H.png)(*StackExchange won't let me upload images because my low reputation*). I want to generate the motif points mapped into the base pattern, shown in **green**.

Having $\overrightarrow{u}=\overrightarrow{Q_1Q_5}$, $\overrightarrow{v}=\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}$ and this transformation matrix

$$\mathbf{T}=\dfrac{1}{\left | \overrightarrow{u} \right |^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\overrightarrow{u}\cdot \overrightarrow{v} & \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \overrightarrow{u}\cdot \overrightarrow{v}\\ 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \overrightarrow{u}\cdot \overrightarrow{v} & \overrightarrow{u}\cdot \overrightarrow{v}
\end{bmatrix}$$

It is true that $$Q_n'=\mathbf{T}\cdot Q_n \hspace{4em} n \in \left(1,2,3,4,5\right)$$

And the trivial cases $Q_1'=P_1$ and $Q_5'=P_2$

---

As you can see, in $\mathbf{T}$ there are a lot of $\overrightarrow{u}\cdot \overrightarrow{v}$ and I'm almost sure the matrix can be rearranged simpler than it is now.

I don't know if this helps, but I noticed the matrix can be rewritten like this:

$$\dfrac{1}{\left | \overrightarrow{u} \right |^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\overrightarrow{u}\cdot \overrightarrow{v} & \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \overrightarrow{u}\cdot \overrightarrow{v}\\ 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \overrightarrow{u}\cdot \overrightarrow{v} & \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\overrightarrow{u}\cdot \overrightarrow{v}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain what it is you are trying to do? Your question isn't clear to me. What are $\overrightarrow{u}$ and $\overrightarrow{v}$, and how does this matrix help you generate a fractal?

Comment: @eigenchris I've edited the question, although I don't think that is very relevant to the question itself.